# what are tb, rl and lr terms in CSS?

Tags: css

I am reading [CSS3 basic box model - collapsing margin](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapsing-margins) but I am unable to figure out `'tb', 'rl' and 'lr'`, terms.

By name it looks like tob bottom for tb and right left for rl but what is the meaning of these terms in below paragraph?

> The top margin of a box A collapses with the top margin of its parent
>   box B if the margins are adjoining and B is ‘tb’.
>
> Note that A itself may be vertical box.
>
> The bottom margin of a box A collapses with the bottom margin of its
>    parent box B if the margins are adjoining and B is ‘tb’.
>
> The left margin of a box A collapses with the left margin of its
>   parent box B if the margins are adjoining and B is ‘rl’ or ‘lr’.
>
> The right margin of a box A collapses with the right margin of its
>   parent box B if the margins are adjoining and B is ‘rl’ or ‘lr’.
>
> The top margin of a box A collapses with the bottom margin of a
>   sibling box B if the margins are adjoining and their parent is ‘tb’.
>
> A right margin of a box A collapses with the left margin of a sibling
>   box B if the margins are adjoining and their parent is ‘rl’ or ‘lr’.

Comment: right-to-left & left-to-right & top-to-bottom

Comment: hmm thanks, should i go ahead and raise a documentation bug/enhancement? For beginners it could be confusing. No reference of these terms in complete document :(

Comment: I wouldn't even worry learning about the writing-mode CSS3 property - I haven't come across it at all in my work and it is only used for "international script modes". Unless you're designing websites in cyrillic or arabic, then I would just skip over that caveat. Mozilla provide a good guide to it here if you're interested though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode

Comment: thanks this link http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-writing-modes/ makes sense

Comment: @adaam Do you want to write up a short summary, the comments would be useful for those of us who follow the quest of reading the W3.org site.